# Typescript doesnt/cant use passed type on generics

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an interface **BaseModel** with method of only get
and is implemented by class **Model**

```js
//interface here...
interface BaseModel {
  get<T>(id: string): T;
}

//class here...

type Fields = {
  [k: string]: string;
}

class Model implements BaseModel{
  public get<Fields>(id: string) {
    ..logic here...
    return {...data} as Fields;
  }
}
```

now when I checked it, it says shadow name(no-shadowed-variables)
and I checked the **Fields get** is **declared but never used**,

Is there any part of the code that I forgot?

Any idea would be great!

Comment: It has nothing to do with typescript, it's your linter that cannot handle this perfectly valid code properly.

Comment: ohh, my linter is `tslint`, and `tslint-config-prettier`

Comment: So you know where to report a bug then. Btw, tslint is deprecated in favour of eslint.

Comment: Oh, it reports it correctly actually: you define a generic `Fields` parameter, so `type Fields` is not used anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I heard, but im gonna wait for a little while sine `typescript-eslint` is somewhat new(`there might also be incompatibility, and a lot of pain as for now`). I also forgot that I used.`tslint:recommended`

Comment: Indeed, `typescript-eslint` does not look ready yet. Still using `tslint` as well.

Comment: @zerkms yeah you're  right!, I forgot that its a `type`, so it can be anything. ugh noob mistake. haha

Answer (score 0):

Your class has the same name as your interface, which is likely causing your linter to get confused. Rename the class or the interface and the linter should be happy.

Comment: Updated, my question, its now `Model` instead of `BaseModel`

I got confused,  Fields in also a `type` in Model class

Answer (score 0):

When you write `get<Fields>(id: string)` you are declaring a new type parameter `Fields`, you are not specializing the method in the interface, which I am assuming was your intention.

You need to declare the type parameter on the interface and specialize it when you declare the `implements`

```
//interface here...
interface BaseModel<T> {
  get(id: string): T;
}

//class here...

type Fields = {
  [k: string]: string;
}

class Model implements BaseModel<Fields>{
  public get(id: string) {
    //..logic here...
    return null! as Fields;
  }
}
```